# Visual Differences within identical code in Webpage from different deployment strategies

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have built a relatively simple MVC Asp.Net Core 2.2 application. When run within Visual Studio, the html/css styling appears correct. However, when packaged into a self contained executable and run on the same machine, the html styling no longer renders correctly. The web app is intended to run locally within an internal network.

I have also deployed the site to an Azure site, and had the same visual issues. I'm not sure if this due to malformed HTML/CSS, however I am not seeing any discernible issues. I'm wondering if some dependencies are not being properly included within the deployment.

What the webpage should look like:
[image]

What the webpage looks like when deployed:
[image]

I can include CSS/HTML if necessary to identify the issue, but was wondering if there were any common problems that cause this.

Comment: How could we possibly help you other than tell you "check all files are there"? Check your browser's development console, there's likely at least 1 error there

Comment: _I'm wondering if some dependencies are not being properly included within the deployment._ ...and after you wondered, did you go and check? We'd love to help, but we physically can't do that task for you. From the screenshot it does seem likely that either some files are missing (CSS or JS likely culprits) or at least that the links the page is using to try and load those files are wrong.

Comment: To be frank, I was having trouble wording the question to solve my issue, Camilo's advice to check the browser's development console has somewhat steered me in the right direction. I checked the file folders themselves and VS's Error/Warning messages and saw no indications of problems, however, I am now seeing a 404 issue regarding site.min.css and site.min.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the minified versions of site.css and site.js. This was identified via a 404 error in the browser development tools.

A similar post, albeit not the correct answer can be found on [ASP.NET Core 2.0: static file (site.min.js) not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097261/asp-net-core-2-0-static-file-site-min-js-not-found).

What fixed mine, and I assume is a less than stellar solution is I copied/pasted the

```
<environment include="Development">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>
```

section within the _layout.cshtml file which was working when running within VS and changed the word "include" in the first line to "exclude". When packaged into an exe, the expecting styling and functionality works as expected.